# How to change a query in mysql so it retrieve 30 rows randomly

Tags: mysql, wordpress, customization

I'd like to change this query in my WordPress plugin so that it retrieves 30 random rows out of 100.

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT
        p.*, qq.quiz_id, qq.question_order AS order
    FROM
       {$wpdb->posts} p 
    INNER JOIN
       {$wpdb->prefix}learnpress_quiz_questions qq ON p.ID = qq.question_id
    WHERE
       qq.quiz_id IN (" . join( ',', $format ) . ")
    AND
       p.post_status = %s
", $args );
```

I've changed it to this but it still does not work. Could any body help me ,please?

```
SELECT
    p.*, qq.quiz_id, qq.question_order AS order
FROM
    {$wpdb->posts} p 
INNER JOIN
    {$wpdb->prefix}learnpress_quiz_questions qq ON p.ID = qq.question_id
WHERE
    qq.quiz_id IN (" . join( ',', $format ) . ")
AND
    p.post_status = %s
ORDER BY
    RAND() LIMIT 30
```

Comment: How have you determined that it "does not work?"  I think it should be working.

Comment: order is a reserved word. as per the error message

Comment: Use backticks around order alias..

Comment: It doesn't show any message. it just retrieves 30 fixed questions NOT random!

Answer (score -1):

Change your sort to something like this:

```
order by RAND() * 30
```

or if you have an integer id:

```
order by RAND() * id
```